# How to optimise a SQL query with a Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table with more than 500k rows and I tried to use an index to get the results faster. I have an index of `_Date` and `_Time` with BTREE and its only works when I query only the columns `_Date` and `_Time`. How can I get the results fast but include all columns? I think that the columns type TEXT are a problem because they do not have a length.

```
SELECT _Date, _Time FROM logsTable
 WHERE TIMESTAMP(_Date, _Time)
 BETWEEN "2021-08-29T13:04" AND "2021-08-29T15:04" 
 LIMIT 135, 15;

#THIS IS THE INDEX THAT ONLY WORKS ONLY WITH _DATE AND _TIME
ALTER TABLE logsTable
ADD INDEX `logsTable_DateTime_Index` USING BTREE (`_Date`, `_Time`) VISIBLE;
```

Table columns:

```
id int AI PK 
raw text 
type1 varchar(100) 
type2 varchar(100) 
desc text 
address1 varchar(100) 
address2 varchar(100) 
num varchar(100) 
_Date date 
_Time time 
serie varchar(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use a generated column and index that

DESC is a reserved word, that should be always avoided as you did with _date or you need rto use backticks

finaly the LIMIT of rows withour an ORDER By is  not a godd idea,, as you can't predict the outcome

> ```
> create table logsTable
> (
> id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
> raw text ,
> type1 varchar(100) ,
> type2 varchar(100) ,
> `desc` text, 
> address1 varchar(100) ,
> address2 varchar(100) ,
> num varchar(100) ,
> _Date date ,
> _Time time ,
> serie varchar(100),
> mytime timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMP(_Date, _Time)) STORED 
> , INDEX `logsTable_DateTime_Index` (mytime));
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN
> SELECT _Date, _Time FROM logsTable
>  WHERE mytime
>  BETWEEN "2021-08-29T13:04" AND "2021-08-29T15:04" 
> ORDER BY mytime
>  LIMIT 135, 15;
> ```

> ```
> id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys            | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                
> -: | :---------- | :-------- | :--------- | :---- | :----------------------- | :----------------------- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :--------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | logsTable | null       | range | logsTable_DateTime_Index | logsTable_DateTime_Index | 5       | null |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af0cf9ff6f57ccc436380fe7cca1e278)*

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT _Date, _Time
FROM logsTable
WHERE _Date = '2021-08-29' AND
      _Time BETWEEN '13:04:00' AND '15:04:00' 
LIMIT 135, 15;
```

And then you want an index on `logsTable(_Date, _Time)`.

And finally . . . you are using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  That is not recommended.  The results come back in *indeterminate* order and could vary from one run of the query to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to assess which columns should be indexed knowing what search operations will be executed in this particular app.

Here is the answer how to index TEXT column:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210403/how-do-you-index-a-text-column-in-mysql

The rest of columns is staightforward - but you need to evaluate if you need indexes on them as each index adds overhead to operations like inserting data.